# Trying to deploy my Aave flashloan test but getting an error. https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box

Tags: javascript, github, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

whenever I run, "truffle test" I get this error below:

```
Error: Mnemonic invalid or undefined
    at checkBIP39Mnemonic (C:\Users\Jackc\node_modules\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\src\index.ts:75:15)
    at new HDWalletProvider (C:\Users\Jackc\node_modules\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\src\index.ts:105:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jackc\truffle-config.js:17:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Function.load (C:\Users\Jackc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:152:1)
    at Function.detect (C:\Users\Jackc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\index.js:144:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\Jackc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\test\run.js:27:1)
    at runCommand (C:\Users\Jackc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command-utils.js:297:1)
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v20.10.0
```

https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box

I have all the correct info in my .env but im not sure if I need to add Mnemonic key into my .env file as it doesnt mention that on the Github page? All it uses in the .env is:

INFURA_API_KEY =
DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY =

I am also using require("dotenv").config() in my truffle-config.js file.

here is the truffle-config.js

```
// const path = require("path");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider")
require("dotenv").config()

module.exports = {
    // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration> to customize your Truffle configuration!
    // contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
    networks: {
      development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 8545,
        // gas: 20000000,
        network_id: "*",
        skipDryRun: true
      },
      ropsten: {
        provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
        network_id: 3,
        gas: 5000000,
        gasPrice: 5000000000, // 5 Gwei
        skipDryRun: true
      },
      kovan: {
        provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY, "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
        network_id: 42,
        gas: 5000000,
        gasPrice: 5000000000, // 5 Gwei
        skipDryRun: true
      },
      mainnet: {
        provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
        network_id: 1,
        gas: 5000000,
        gasPrice: 5000000000 // 5 Gwei
      }
    },
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "^0.6.6",
        },
    },
}
```

Starting to think it might be a dependency issue in my package.json but I am just guessing by this point.

any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Without looking into it too deeply, the repository you’ve linked hasn’t had a commit in over 4 years. I’d frankly be surprised if it worked straight out of the box without any snags.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle is Depreciated , switch to foundry or Hardhat if the problem persists (old code wont be useful either from github as well as courses)